# Powershell - remove duplicates from 2 arrays using wildcards

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates, wildcard

I am trying to remove duplicates and leave only unique entries from the output of 2 queries.

I am pulling a list of installed Windows Updates using the following (also stripping 12 chars of whitespace and dropping to lower case:

```
$A = @(Get-HotFix | select-object @{Expression={$_.HotFixID.ToLower()}} | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String) -replace '\s{12}',''
```

I am then querying a list of available files in a folder and stripping 3 trailing whitespace chars using:

```
$B = @(Get-ChildItem D:\y | select-object 'Name' | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String) -replace '\s{3}',''
```

The problem I have is that the first query ($A) returns output like:

```
kb4040981
kb4041693
kb2345678
kb8765432
```

While the second query ($B) returns output like:

```
windows8.1-kb4040981-x64_d1eb05bc8c55c7632779086079c7759f40d7386f.cab
windows8.1-kb4041687-x64_3bdf264bcfc0dda01c2eaf2135e322d2d6ce6c64.cab
windows8.1-kb4041693-x64_359b7ac71a48e5af003d67e3e4b80120a2f5b570.cab
windows8.1-kb4049179-x64_e6ec21d5d16fa6d8ff890c0c6042c2ba38a1f7c4.cab
```

I need to compare the 2 outputs using wildcards around each entry in the $A array (I think), and where it exists in $B remove the entire line from $B array.

I cannot truncate the output of $B as I need to use the full filenames in a subsequent process.

IE in the example output above, the entire FIRST and THIRD lines would be remove from the $B array and other lines left intact.

I have tried numerous methods from online searches, and used foreach loops, all to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try with foreach loops that didn't work? Unless your output is huge, this method is pretty striaght forward.

```
$a = "kb4040981","kb4041693","kb2345678","kb8765432","test"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$b = "windows8.1-kb4040981-x64_d1eb05bc8c55c7632779086079c7759f40d7386f.cab","windows8.1-kb4041687-x64_3bdf264bcfc0dda01c2eaf2135e322d2d6ce6c64.cab","windows8.1-kb4041693-x64_359b7ac71a48e5af003d67e3e4b80120a2f5b570.cab","windows8.1-kb4049179-x64_e6ec21d5d16fa6d8ff890c0c6042c2ba38a1f7c4.cab"

$toRemove = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($kb in $a)
{
    foreach($line in $b)
    {
        if($line -match $kb)
        {
            write-host "$kb found in: $line" -ForegroundColor Green
            $toRemove.add($line) | out-null
        }
    }
}

foreach($line in $toRemove)
{
    $b.Remove($line)
}

$b
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That does work if the arrays are declared, but not when the variables are created from queries as per my initial post.  I have tried outputting the query to text files and importing them again, however this doesn't work.  I think it may be something to do with the multi-line output, but unsure. I am still persisting, and any other pointers are greatly appreciated!  Thanks again.

Comment: There's no reason you should be sending them to files and reading them back in. What do you mean by "doesn't work" what's the output you get vs. What you're expecting?

Comment: The output is the full query assigned to $B, ie no removal of duplicates occurs.  That is using the exact same code that you suggested but replacing the declared strings with the queries as per OP.  I have also tried other code that has the same effect.  In other words, the output of the 2 queries seems harder to do a compare and remove dupes.
Thank you.

Comment: Its likely due to the weird way you're formatting the output. Using format-table, out-string, and your -replace all seem odd. Why not just `(Get-ChildItem D:\y -file).name` and `(get-hofix).hotfixID)`? You would definitely benefit from learning the fundamentals.

Comment: Thank you, you were completely correct.  Once I simplified the query your earlier code worked perfectly.
Again, thanks for your patience and input.  I will indeed study up more!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for you to take a little time to learn the very basics of Powershell. When you use format cmdlets and text files instead of objects you cut yourself of the good stuff.  ;-)
Here is how I would start the task:

```
$A = Get-HotFix
$B = Get-ChildItem D:\y | Select-Object -Property Name,@{Name='HotFixID';Expression={($_.BaseName -split '-')[1]}}
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B -Property 'HotFixID' -PassThru
```

Comment: I got a bit further if I specify a string, but this still does not do a real comparison of the output from the first query.  Sorry if I don't know Powershell better, that's why I am asking here after 2 days of searching and testing other methods.

`code`   Get-ChildItem D:\y | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'kb4074588'} | Set-Content c:\z\result.txt    `code`

Comment: That's why I recommended to learn the basics. You cannot learn by guessing or copying code together you don't understand. Did you try the code I posted? What happend? You should read the help for all cmdlets you use (cmdlets I posted) completely incl. the examples. You might start here: [Getting Started with Microsoft PowerShell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382) .. it does not take long but it will push you fast forward.

Answer (score 0):

Sincere thanks to sambardo for his patience and input!  The final working solution based on his excellent recommendation is:

```
$a = (Get-Hotfix).hotfixID
$b = (Get-ChildItem D:\y\ -file *.cab).name
$toRemove = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  foreach($kb in $a)
{
    foreach($line in $b)
  {
      if($line -match $kb)
    {
#            write-host "$kb found in: $line" -ForegroundColor Green
            $toRemove.add($line) | out-null
      }
    }
}
foreach($line in $toRemove)
{
  $b.Remove($line)
}
$b
```